# How would I determine if a varchar field in SQL contains any numeric characters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a project where we have to figure out if a given field is potentially a company name versus an address.

In taking a very broad swipe at it, we are going under the assumption that if this field contains no numbers, odds are it is a name vs. a street address (we're aiming for the 80% case, knowing some will have to be done manually).

So now to the question at hand.  Given a table with, for the sake of simplicity, a single varchar(100) column, how could I find those records who have no numeric characters at any position within the field?

For example:

```
"Main Street, Suite 10A" --Do not return this.
"A++ Billing" --Should be returned
"XYZ Corporation" --Should be returned
"100 First Ave, Apt 20" --Should not be returned
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sql Server allows for a regex-like syntax for range `[0-9]` or Set `[0123456789]` to be specified in a [`LIKE` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx), which can be used with the any string wildcard (`%`). For example:

```
select * from Address where StreetAddress not like '%[0-9]%';
```

The wildcard `%` at the start of the `like` will obviously hurt performance (Scans are likely), but in your case this seems inevitable.

[Another MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

```
select * from table where column not like '%[0-9]%'
```

This query returns you all rows from table where column does not contain any of the digits from 0 to 9.

Comment: Did not work - query above is including all records other than those that are null or blank.

Answer (score 8):

I like the simple regex approach, but for the sake of discussion will mention this alternative which uses **PATINDEX**.

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber from Invoices WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', InvoiceNumber) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me .

```
select total_employee_count from company_table where total_employee_count  like  '%[^0-9]%'
```

This returned all rows that contains non numeric values including 2-3 ..

Answer (score 3):

This Query to list out Tables created with numeric Characters

```
select * from SYSOBJECTS where xtype='u' and  name  like '%[0-9]%'
```