# how to query a table to find rows where there are no numbers in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that has numbers and `characters` in `SQL Server 2005`

Note: Here `character` means anything other than a number.

I need to list all records that has a character in it (other than numbers). Following query will list a record if there are no numbers in a record. But I need to list all records that has characters in it irrespective of whether it has number or not.

How to modify this query to return all records that has atlesat one character?

**Reference**:

1. [How would I determine if a varchar field in SQL contains any numeric characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324912/how-would-i-determine-if-a-varchar-field-in-sql-contains-any-numeric-characters)
2. [SQL query for finding rows with special characters only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968042/sql-query-for-finding-rows-with-special-characters-only?rq=1)

**CODE**

```
DECLARE @WorkOrderHistory TABLE (WorkOrder VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @WorkOrderHistory (WorkOrder) VALUES ('123456') --EXCLUDE from result
INSERT INTO @WorkOrderHistory (WorkOrder) VALUES ('abvc@@@') --Need to list in result
INSERT INTO @WorkOrderHistory (WorkOrder) VALUES ('a+bvc1234') --Need to list in result
INSERT INTO @WorkOrderHistory (WorkOrder) VALUES ('++') --Need to list in result
INSERT INTO @WorkOrderHistory (WorkOrder) VALUES ('$1') --Need to list in result
INSERT INTO @WorkOrderHistory (WorkOrder) VALUES ('1.2')  --Need to list in result

--Any record without a number
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM @WorkOrderHistory WO  
WHERE WO.WorkOrder NOT like '%[0-9]%'
```

Comment: Please provide sample output, what you want the query to return as a result.

Comment: @tsHunter Updated the question with expected output

Comment: So you are looking for columns which don't have integers in them? What about *123.23* or *$2,302*

Comment: @AdmiralAdama 123.23 should be listed in the result. For my scenario that is not a number alone. I will update the sample in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carat (^) inside a [] bracket means match any character except for those in the list.  So if you want to match any character except for 0-9, you use [^0-9] and the LIKE (without the NOT) will match all other characters.

This should work:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM @WorkOrderHistory WO  
WHERE WO.WorkOrder LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Of course, you'll match all punctuation, and unprintable characters as well.

Via [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?  I thought it worked... I edited to elaborate a bit.

Comment: I didn't... there's no orange arrow on the question, but I'll be glad to upvote it to counter; I think it's an OK question.

Comment: OP Stated he can't match punctuation

Comment: I thought he stated he DID want punctuation: "123.23 should be listed in the result" was OP's quote.  This returns both "1.2" and "$1", which I still think is the request.

Comment: Ahh sorry when I scanned your answer I got the logic on matching mixed up. I think this is the answer +1

Answer (score 0):

select * from sales 
where name not like '%[0-9]%'

Comment: try explaining and elaborating on your query

Answer (score -1):

Use [IsNumeric](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    Select isNumeric(workorders) as isNumber,WorkOrder from table @workorderhistory) AS BOB
WHERE BOB.isNumber = 0
```

Comment: `isNumeric` returns 1 if the number is convertible to a number. It doesn't scan for a number in a string.

Comment: `IsNumeric` accepts monetary amounts like `$1,000.00`.

Comment: OP just wants to see if a column is a number or a mix of characters. so in this case IsNumeric will give the needed value stating that the column is only a number or not

Comment: Instead of a subquery why don't you just do `WHERE ISNUMERIC(workorders) != 1` ?

Comment: @michealmgriff ops edit came in mid writing of answer, i just havent changed it yet