# Selecting all rows with a column that doesn't contain any digits

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to select all records from a certain table within my PostgreSQL database using a simple regex. The table in question is a table of inventory items, and each item has a `partno`. There are a couple of entries in this table, whose part numbers are only letters (ie, `DISCOUNT`, `REBATE`, etc). Other part numbers are a combination of letters and numbers (ie, 100H, 250H300, etc.)

I want to delete these entries. Before deletion, I am trying to simply select the records, but I am failing.

I have tried some queries such as:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE partno ~ '\b([a-z]+)\b'; // Returns nothing

SELECT * FROM items WHERE partno ~ '[A-Z]+'; // This returns *everything*

SELECT * FROM items WHERE partno ~ '\b[^\d\W]+\b'; // Returns nothing
```

Especially the last query I can't figure out why it's returning nothing.
Is there a better way to return all records where `partno` has *no* digits?

I don't know how to edit this to make it clear that I did my homework and none of the established answers are working for me. I guess the examples of what I've tried and how it doesn't work somehow isn't enough?
PostgreSQL 14

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to query a table to find rows where there are no numbers in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273366/how-to-query-a-table-to-find-rows-where-there-are-no-numbers-in-a-column)

Comment: No, that returns no records.

Answer (score 2):

You said 2 different things:

1/ if you are looking for part numbers which are only letters (ie, DISCOUNT, REBATE, etc) **and** part numbers which are a combination of letters and numbers (ie, 100H, 250H300, etc.)

```
select * 
  from items
 where partno !~ '^\d$';
```

2/ if you are looking for all records where partno has no digits
as @Belayer said , this will do it

```
 select * 
  from items
 where partno !~ '\d';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for *partno has no digits*. The [regexp operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) `!~` says find columns that **do not match** the expresion, so just look for at last 1 digit. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hTtkPqfe))

```
select * 
  from items
 where partno !~ '\d';
```